# Angular 16 - Router outlet activate event

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components, angular16, angular-router-events

We migrated our angular application from angular v13 to v16. The component's lifecycle events were working fine in v13, but having an issue in v16 when routing from one component to another.

In our component HTML, there is a router activate event defined.
`<router-outlet (activate)="activateEvent($event)/>` and also an `ngOnInit` event is defined in component ts file.

**Angular v13**
When we're trying to do `router.navigate` from our home page to the above component, the event is fired in below sequence

1. Component `activateEvent` is fired
2. Component `ngOnInit` is fired

**Angular v16**
When trying the same thing with a newer version, the sequence of events has changed.

1. Component `ngOnInit` is fired
2. Component `activateEvent` is fired

As the events are not fired correctly, so causing an issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

The sequence of events of components should be same.